# how to use list.filter when the function called has several parameters, in F#?

Tags: f#

I'm trying to do the following in F#, from pseudo C# code:

```
Data? MyFunc(a, b, c) { ... } 
var result = new List<Data>();    
foreach (var i in MyData)
{
    var r = MyFunc(something, somethingelse, i);
    if (r != null) result.add((Data)r);
}
```

I have 2 questions:

- Is there an equivalent of List.filter that will allow to check if the result of my function call is None or not?
- How can I invoke a function through a list if some of the parameters do not come from the list iterator? like something and somethingelse in my example?

(beginning in F#, the answer may be trivial)

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`List.choose`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/list.choose%5B%27t%2C%27u%5D-function-%5Bfsharp%5D):

```
let myData a b c = ...

let collect somthing somethingElse myData =
    myData |> List.choose (myFunc something somethingElse)
```

If the list element is not the last element to `myFunc` you can't use partial application but can use a function e.g.

```
myData |> List.choose (fun e -> myFunc something e somethingElse)
```

Comment: looks like I have a million list functions to learn with F# :) two quick questions: 1) the list element has to be the last parameter of myFunc, correct? and also if myFunc returns something like (float, int), what would be the correct syntax? (that gives me: [FS0001] The type ''a option' does not match the type 'Nullable<float> * Nullable<int>')

Comment: @Thomas - Yes to use partial application you need the list element to be the last argument, see update. What is the return type of `MyData`? Your question suggests it's an `option 'a`, but your comment indicates it's `(float? ,int?)`. Do you want to produce a `list (float, int)`?

Comment: @Thomas - Can you change `myData` to return a `(float, int) option` directly? Or is it an external function you can't change?

Comment: it's a C# function, so I can make it (float?, int?) but that's it

Comment: @Thomas - Regarding the "million list functions to learn with F#", bookmark https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/list-module-functions/ right now. You'll come back to it time and time again. Eventually you'll know all these functions by heart, but until then, that page is by far the best reference to them that I've ever found.